# How to create a string / string array from a .txt/.xml file?

Tags: android, arrays, regex, android-studio

I know it has been asked a million times, but I just can't find anything that Works, and I just started learning to code

I'm trying to use regex to tell when the user types any of 118 different patterns, so you can guess it'd be a really long string, and I have all the patterns in a .txt/.xml file and I want to create a string or array with these patterns

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tv1;
private EditText et3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);

}

public void boton (View view){

    String text = et3.getText().toString();

    //String[] symbolsArr = {"He|","H|","Os|","O"};

    //StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    //for(int i = 0; i < symbolsArr.length; i++) {  //all of this is just to convert an array to a single string
    //    sb.append(symbolsArr[i]);
    //

    String symbols = "Zr|Zn|Yb|Y|Xe|W|V|U|Ts|Tm|Tl|Ti|Th|Te|Tc|Tb|Ta|Sr|Sn|Sm|Si|Sg|Se|Sc|Sb|S|Ru|Rn|Rh|Rg|Rf|Re|Rb|Ra|Pu|Pt|Pr|Po|Pm|Pd|Pb|Pa|P|Os|Og|O|Np|No|Ni|Nh|Ne|Nd|Nb|Na|N|Mt|Mo|Mn|Mg|Md|Mc|Lv|Lu|Lr|Li|La|Kr|K|Ir|In|I|Hs|Ho|Hg|Hf|He|H|Ge|Gd|Ga|Fr|Fm|Fl|Fe|F|Eu|Es|Er|Dy|Ds|Db|Cu|Cs|Cr|Co|Cn|Cm|Cl|Cf|Ce|Cd|Ca|C|Br|Bk|Bi|Bh|Be|Ba|B|Au|At|As|Ar|Am|Al|Ag|Ac";
    //The really long string with all the patterns

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(symbols);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    tv1.setText("");

    while (m.find()){
        tv1.append("found " + m.group() + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the input and what are you expecting so that it will be easy for us to figure out the solution for you i.e. .txt and .xml format which you mentioned

Comment: What do you mean by input? What the user will type? In that case it is at least one of those patterns. What contains the .txt file? It has all the patterns either on a single string or one each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of how do you want to storage the file.
For example let`s use assets.
Put file `data.txt` in `assets`(you can create this in File/New/Folder/Assets Folder)

After that you can create method, wich help you to get string from assetFile

```
public String getStringFromAssetFile(Context context, String nameFile)
    {
        String str = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(nameFile)));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str += line;

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Now you can use this method to create a string or array with these patterns

```
String symbols = getStringFromAssetFile(MainActivity.this, "data.txt");
```